# How to Hide a HTML Button

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a button that calls a function when it is clicked. I want it to hide when some one clicks on it.

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="Displayer"></p>
        <button onclick="Set()">Ready?</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in your element and then set the `display` style to `none`:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="set(this)">Ready?</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function set(elem) {
    elem.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping